# Is there a different syntax for creating environments in base R?

Tags: r, environment

Suppose that I wanted to create a new environment with members `a=5`, `b=6`, and `c=7`. This is the best way that I know:

```
e<-new.env()
e$a<-5
e$b<-6
e$c<-7
```

Compared to the equivalent syntax for lists, which would just be `e<-list(a=5,b=6,c=7)`, this is a pain. I know that the Tidyverse has a better way of doing this, but what about base R? Is there a different syntax for creating environments and adding elements?

Comment: You could use `list2env(list(a = 5, b = 6, c = 7), envir = e)`

Comment: You could also run `evalq({a<-5; b<-6; c<-7}, e)`.

Comment: @akrun Might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we create a named `list`, an option to create objects would be `list2env`.  The `envir` can be `.GlobalEnv` (creates objects on the global environment) or a custom environment (`e`)

```
list2env(list(a = 5, b = 6, c = 7), envir = e)
```